# Where to provide logic rules for validation

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a file exporter and validate the field types as strings, dates etc + also the field count of each row.

Now, where would one keep the rules for such logic so that the class responsible for creating the csv is generic and decoupled from any business logic and that should business needs change then the exported class need never be amended.

I had though about creating a second class used for business logic but that would require the following - both equally as bad i think:

- hard coded rules inside the class
- rules to be passed to constructor

There doesn seem to be a good solution but this must be a common problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as usual it depends..

responsiblity of the data lies with the provider. "fileExporter" as mentioned will export the file, if the data provider is sealed then obviously you would have create an validator which will assert the data, subsequently the asserted data would be passed to the file exporter.

If it is not sealed you could inject dependencies into it.

i.e.

```
class DataProvider(IDataValidator dataValidator, IFileFormat fileFormat){...}
interface IFileFormat { void Export();}
interface IDataValidator { void AsserData(); }
class CSVDataValidator : IDataValidator{...}
class CSVFileExporter : IFileExporter {..}

var dataValidator = new CSVDataValidator();
var iFileFormat = new CSVFileFormat();
var dataProvider = new DataProvider(dataValidator, fileFormat);
var data = dataProvider.Data;
var csvFileExporter = new CSVFileExporter(data)
csvFileExporter.Export();
```

basically the possibilities are endless, **it just depends what it is you would like to close and what is it that you wish to extend in the future**

I would read upon strategy / dependency injection / open close principle

Comment: So in the example provided both the datavalidator and fileformat would both have to know about the format of the csv i.e. number of fields etc ?

Comment: Wow - that makes sense now.  Lots of classes though, but i guess thats the price to pay for very extensible designs

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try with a chain of responsibility pattern. Your client owns a list of Validator object each one realizing a Validator Interface with a method (i.e. validate) returning true if the content passed as parameter is "valid". Each component has its own validation criterion which is however black boxed to the client that uses it through its generic interface. So when you build up the system you instantiate your client and inject the validators you need.

Comment: So the validation rules are hardcoded inside the validation class?

Comment: A ValidatorClient delegates a list of Validators to validate a content. If they all return true then the content is valid. The class which creates the ValidatorClient injects the validators. See http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern